# Error "Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException" from SonarQube in android

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube, sonar-android-plugin

We are getting the above exception followed by

> Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.sonarqube', version: '2.6.2',
>   apply:false]
>   in our android app.

We have

> minSdkVersion 19

and

> targetSDKVersion 23

and

> buildToolsVersion 27.0.3

and android studio 3.0.1.

Our Sonarqube plugin is 2.6.2 as you probably have guessed it.The app then time out and fail to compile. Can someone point me to fix this issue?

Comment: Please add some more context. Which SonarQube version do you use? Did you change something in your (existing?) setup? Did you inspect all SonarQube logs?

Comment: This is my first time using SonarQube and I don't know where the logs are located.

Comment: You can find all SonarQube logs in the log directory under the root directory of your installation. The log level can be set in the configuration file sonar.properties found in the conf directory.

Comment: @Jeroen Heier, I wasn't able to locate that log in the root. In the log file I have, all I see is our own logs and not SonarQube.